# increment onclick counter for game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to create a easy game to go on a website

my idea is that there are five red letters hidden around one web page for people to find.
When they click on a letter it disappears.

so lets say there are 5 letters i want the jquery or js to count that they have found five letters and change a seperate div with a form in it from "display none" to "display block"

this is what i have so far

i am struggling to get it to count the 'letters' as they are clicked

```
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <a id="hideaway1" class="red-Letter" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='none';">red letter 1</a>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway2').style.display='none';">red letter 2</a>
                <a id="hideaway3" class="red-Letter" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway3').style.display='none';">red letter 3</a>
                <a id="hideaway4" class="red-Letter" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway4').style.display='none';">red letter 4</a>
                <a id="hideaway5" class="red-Letter" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway5').style.display='none';">red letter 5</a>

                <p>The red letters was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                      var count = 0;
                      var redLetter = $('.red-Letter').attr('class');
                      var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

                      redLetter.onclick = function(){
                        count++;
                        display.innerHTML = count;
                      }
                </script>
```

Comment: ok, whats the question, what bit are your stuck on?

Comment: im stuck on getting it to count the 'letters' as they are clicked

Comment: `var redLetter = $('.red-Letter').attr('class');` if your just getting reletter as a selector you dont need the `.attr('class')` part - Just use `$('.red-Letter')`

Comment: `onclick` is a method of DOM element whereas `redLetter` is a jQuery object. You have to use `.click` method

Comment: onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway1').style.display='none';"
 == 
onClick="this.style.display='none';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery you can really clean this up (no `id`s, no `onclick`) and accomplish it with with a simple `click()` function, Setting `$(this)` to `.hide()` and incrementing a variable. No need to use a mix of plain JS and jQuery:

**JS**

```
var counter = 0;

$(".red-Letter").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  counter++;
  $("#displayCount").html(counter); //you could use .text() but incase you ever wanted to add other elements, doesn't hurt to already be using .html()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 1</a>
<a href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 2</a>
<a href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 3</a>
<a href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 4</a>
<a href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 5</a>

<p>The red letters was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7aqgqbr/)

Comment: how would i then use the counter once it reaches 5 to do something i have tried this

  if (counter === 5) {
   alert("form");
  }

but it doesnt work

Comment: Thats correct, just make sure it's being called after it increments (`counter++`) otherwise it wouldn't fire until the 6th click: [http://jsfiddle.net/z7aqgqbr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/z7aqgqbr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your javascript to this:

```
var count = 0;
var redLetter = $('.red-Letter');
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

redLetter.on("click", function(){
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
});
```

This binds to the click event of elements with the class red-letter

Comment: This helped me out anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0e5hx4oh/)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="hideaway1" href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 1</a>
<a id="hideaway2" href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 2</a>
<a id="hideaway3" href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 3</a>
<a id="hideaway4" href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 4</a>
<a id="hideaway5" href="#" class="red-Letter">red letter 5</a>
<p>The red letters was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

<script>

$(function() {
  var count = 0,
  redLetter = $('.red-Letter'),
  display = $("#displayCount");

  redLetter.on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    count++;
    display.text(count);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in the code

```
var redLetter = $('.red-Letter').attr('class');
// this gives you the class, try
var redLetter = $('.red-Letter');

var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
// your using jquery, mayas well use it, try
var display = $('#displayCount');

redLetter.onclick = function(){
// again with jquery try
redLetter.on('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/85/

```
<a id="hideaway1" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 1</a>
<a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 2</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $('.red-Letter').on('click', function() {
        count++;
        $("#displayCount").text(count);
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your java script function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                      var count = 0;
                      var redLetter = $('.red-Letter').attr('class');
```

**`//This is wrong - it just return class Name - a value not a Jquery Object`**

```
 var display = document.getElementById("displayCount"); **`// you can use jQuery`**

                      **redLetter.onclick = function(){
                        count++;
                        display.innerHTML = count;
                      }**
```

The above will do nothing

```
Use : $('.red-Letter').on('click',function(){
             count++;
             display.innerHTML = count;

});
                    </script>
```

you should store count in a hidden input variable //

```
<input id="count" type="hidden" value="0"/> //Makes it easy to retain state.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.red-Letter', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var counterSpan = $('#displayCount'); 
  var counter = counterSpan.html();
  counterSpan.html(parseInt(counter) + 1);
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.red-Letter {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#" >red letter 1</a>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#" >red letter 2</a>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#" >red letter 3</a>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#" >red letter 4</a>
                <a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#" >red letter 5</a>

                <p>The red letters was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="hideaway1" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 1</a>
<a id="hideaway2" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 2</a>
<a id="hideaway3" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 3</a>
<a id="hideaway4" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 4</a>
<a id="hideaway5" class="red-Letter" href="#">red letter 5</a>

<p>The red letters was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $('body').on('click', '.red-Letter', clickedLetter);

    function clickedLetter(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
      count += 1;
      $('#displayCount').text(count);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an object that holds the count value and have a method to increase the count by one in the object. Call the method in your event handler.

```
var redLetter = $('.red-Letter').attr('class');
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

// Make a separate object so that you don't clutter the global namespace
var counter = {
    count: 0,
};
counter.inc = function(){
    this.count++;
};

redLetter.onclick = function(){
                    counter.inc();
                    display.innerHTML = counter.count;
                  }
```